# Outputting values for a function

Tags: matlab

I have a question regarding the output of functions. This is the part of my function that I am having trouble with.

```
    function [T,p,rho] = atmplot(h);

    ...

    if (h>=0 & h<=11000)

        [T,p,rho] = Gradient(T_base,a1,h,h_base,p_base,g0,R);

    else

        [T_base,p_base,~] = Gradient(288.16,a1,11000,0,101325,g0,R);

        h_base=11000;

    end

    if (h>11000 & h<=25000);

        [T,p,rho] = Isothermal(T_base,h,h_base,p_base,g0,R)

    else 

        [T_base,p_base,~] = Isothermal(T_base,25000,h_base,p_base,g0,R);

        h_base=25000;

    end
```

Here, `h` is a user-inputted array of values. When I enter a value between 0 and 11000, the values returned are in an array but anything above that value returns nothing. When it gets to this part:

```
    if (h>11000 & h<=25000);

        [T,p,rho] = Isothermal(T_base,h,h_base,p_base,g0,R)

    else 

        [T_base,p_base,~] = Isothermal(T_base,25000,h_base,p_base,g0,R);

        h_base=25000;

    end
```

If I enter a value between 11000 and 25000 it does not compute `[T,p,rho]`, instead it goes to compute a new `T_base` and `p_base`. I would like it to output an array of values for each variable from `0:h`. Is there any way I could achieve this? This is the layout our instructor gave us to use but it is not working. The two functions used do work as I use them without a problem in another script. Let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: So `h` is an array rather than a scalar? If so then what is the correct behavior if `h=[1 11001]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `h` is a vector or array rather than a scalar, then your `if` statements aren't correct. A statement like `h>=0 & h<=11000` returns a logical (Boolean) array of the same size as `h`. However, `if` statements only operate on scalars. If `h>=0 & h<=11000` returns a vector, only the first element will be used to decide which code to execute.

If you still want to pass in a vector (or array) for `h` you'll need to vectorize your `if` statements and all of the code within them. The functions `any` and `all` can be helpful for this, e.g.:

```
if all(h(:)>=0 & h(:)<=11000)

    ... % All h in first range

elseif all(h(:)>11000 & h(:)<=25000)

    ... % All h in second range

elseif all(h(:)>=0 & h(:)<=25000)

    ... % Some h in first range and some in second, requires more processing

else

    ... % Case where all h outside of both ranges

end
```

Another option is to wrap the `if` statements in a `for` loop and iterate over each value of `h` – maybe something like this:

```
numh = numel(h);
T = zeros(numh,1);
p = zeros(numh,1);
rho = zeros(numh,1);
for i = 1:numh
    ...

    if h(i)>=0 && h(i)<=11000
        [T(i),p(i),rho(i)] = Gradient(T_base,a1,h(i),h_base,p_base,g0,R);
    else
        [T_base,p_base,~] = Gradient(288.16,a1,11000,0,101325,g0,R);
        h_base=11000;
    end

    ...
end
```

You'll have to fill in the details in both cases as your example code is quite incomplete. As you can see it might just be easier to put your main `atmplot` function in a `for` loop and iterate over the elements of `h`.

Comment: If i vectorize the if statements, can i put 'any' in front of all my if conditions without having to do the 'all' example you have?

Comment: @aerogummi: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you use `any(h(:)>=0 & h(:)<=11000)` instead, the associated statement would be triggered if *any* of the elements of `h` are within that range. The problem is that there may be elements outside of the range too so your functions like `Gradient` would need to handle them. I'm not sure if that's what you want and I'm not sure what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: Like I say at the end, vectorization in such cases can be tricky (I'm not sure it would gain you much) – the simplest way to deal with this is to wrap you `atmplot` function in a `for` loop, only pass in `h(i)`, and save the output on each iteration.